# different results regression directly vs a generic sklearn function

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am getting different results when I do a simple linear regression directly vs a function that can accept any modelling parameters and do cross-validation. That seems to be the only difference to me but why are the results so different.

#### Using linear_model.LinearRegression() directly

```
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(features.values,target.values)
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(x_train, y_train)
print(np.mean((regr.predict(x_test) - y_test) ** 2))
```

#### Results:

```
395.68
```

#### Using generic function

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

def cv_predict_report(func,params,features,target,fold,verbose=False):
    model_details,rmse = [],[]
    kf = KFold(n_splits=fold)

    for train_ix, test_ix in kf.split(features):

        x_train_poly, x_test_poly = features.iloc[train_ix].values,features.iloc[test_ix].values
        y_train,y_test = target.iloc[train_ix],target.iloc[test_ix]

        #model
        model = func(**params)
        model.fit(csr_matrix(x_train_poly),y_train)

        #save model details
        model_details.append(model)

        #predictions
        preds = model.predict(x_test_poly)

        model_rmse = np.mean((preds - y_test) ** 2)
        rmse.append(model_rmse)

    return model_details,rmse
```

#### Call function with linear_model.LinearRegression

```
from sklearn import linear_model
lm_model,lm_rmse = cv_predict_report(linear_model.LinearRegression,{},features,target,fold = 2)
print(lm_rmse)
```

#### Results

```
[440.2067193330667, 437.6263639733618]
```

Comment: Why do you expect `train_test_split` to give you the same split as `KFold`?

Comment: I agree the splits would be different in each case. But I dont think thats the only reason for the huge difference in their MSEs. Or can it? I tried multiple runs of train_test_split with different random_state. The results dont fluctuate much at all.

Comment: The difference in MSEs is about 10%, no? That isn't what I would call **huge**, and certainly, is *well* within the realm of variability of what I would expect from using different splits of a dataset to train the same model. Furthermore, it isn't the random state that is the issue, it is the different sizes of the training sets. `train_test_split` uses a 0.25 split by default. You are using 2-folds with `KFold`, which would be a 0.50 split. Try it with `folds=4`

Comment: I tried a 4 fold spit and the mse are still with in 436 - 440 range.  Probably you are right that the differences are only with in 10% and I am okay if this is the result of differences in splitting. But I am concerned since they just dont overlap how much ever times I run them. train_test_split has been below 400 all through and kfold has always been above 435s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i just realized what the problem was. The generic function calls 'csr_matrix' that is behaving weirdly and causing higher errors. i will read on csr_matrix and why it is causing this difference